# RabbitMQ BasicAck makes next message UnAck

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Here is the scenario

At the start,
Ready Queue : 2
UnAcked: 0

Once the `consumer.Queue.Dequeue(1000, out bdea);` runs,

ReadyQueue: 1
UnAcked: 1
This is obvious, where we read one message and not Acknowledged yet.

Problem is that when the `channel.BasicAck(bdea.DeliveryTag, false);` runs,

ReadyQueue: 0
UnAcked: 1

Message which was in the Ready state became UnAcked and ReadyQueue becomes "0" !!

Now, in the while loop, when we look for the second message with `consumer.Queue.Dequeue(1000, out bdea);`, bdea returns null as there is nothing in the Ready state.

This is the issue, when there an Ack happens, always it drags a message from the Ready queue to UnAck. Therefore the next time I am loosing this UnAcked message which was never dequeued.

But if I stop the process (Console App), UnAck message goes back to Ready State.

Assume there are 10 messages in Ready state at the start, at the end it will only process 5 where you find 5 messages in UnAcked state. Each Ack makes the next message UnAck. If I stop and run again (5 messages in Ready state), guess what, 3 messages will gets processed, 2 will be UnAcked. (Dequeue only picks half of the no of messages)

Here is my code (code which only has the RabbitMQ functionality, issue is there if you try this code as well),

```
public class TestMessages
{
    private ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    string billingFileId = string.Empty;
    private IConnection connection = null;
    private IModel channel = null;
    public void Listen()
    {
        try
        {
            #region CONNECT
            factory.AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true;
            factory.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MQUserName"];
            factory.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MQPassword"];
            factory.VirtualHost = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MQVirtualHost"];
            factory.HostName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MQHostName"];
            factory.Port = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MQPort"]);
            #endregion


            RabbitMQ.Client.Events.BasicDeliverEventArgs bdea;
            using (connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            {
                string jobId = string.Empty;
                using (IModel channel = connection.CreateModel())
                {
                    while (true) //KEEP LISTNING
                    {
                        if (!channel.IsOpen)
                            throw new Exception("Channel is closed"); //Exit the loop.

                        QueueingBasicConsumer consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel);

                        //Prefetch 1 message
                        channel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);

                        String consumerTag = channel.BasicConsume(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MQQueueName"], false, consumer);

                        try
                        {
                            //Pull out the message
                            consumer.Queue.Dequeue(1000, out bdea);
                            if (bdea == null)
                            {
                                //Empty Queue
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                IBasicProperties props = bdea.BasicProperties;
                                byte[] body = bdea.Body;
                                string message = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(bdea.Body);

                                try
                                {

                                    channel.BasicAck(bdea.DeliveryTag, false);

                                    ////Heavy work starts now......

                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    //Log

                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            //Log it
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteLog.Error(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            //CleanUp();
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with the "Subscription" rather than the Channel and it works now, clears up the message queue. I referred to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18610959/rabbit-mq-unack-message-not-back-to-queue-for-consumer-to-process-again).

Here is the working code:

```
public void SubscribeListner()
{
    Subscription subscription = null;
    const string uploaderExchange = "myQueueExchange";
    string queueName = "myQueue";
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            if (subscription == null)
            {
                try
                {
                   //CONNECT Code

                    //try to open connection
                    connection = factory.CreateConnection();
                }
                catch (BrokerUnreachableException ex)
                {
                    //You probably want to log the error and cancel after N tries, 
                    //otherwise start the loop over to try to connect again after a second or so.
                    //log.Error(ex);
                    continue;
                }

                
                //crate chanel
                channel = connection.CreateModel();
                // This instructs the channel not to prefetch more than one message
                channel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);
                // Create a new, durable exchange
                channel.ExchangeDeclare(uploaderExchange, ExchangeType.Direct, true, false, null);
                // Create a new, durable queue
                channel.QueueDeclare(queueName, true, false, false, null);
                // Bind the queue to the exchange
                channel.QueueBind(queueName, uploaderExchange, queueName);
                //create subscription
                subscription = new Subscription(channel, uploaderExchange, false);
            }
            BasicDeliverEventArgs eventArgs;
            var gotMessage = subscription.Next(250, out eventArgs);//250 millisecond
            if (gotMessage)
            {
                if (eventArgs == null)
                {
                    //This means the connection is closed.
                    //DisposeAllConnectionObjects();
                    continue;//move to new iterate
                }

                //process message
                subscription.Ack(); 
                //channel.BasicAck(eventArgs.DeliveryTag, false);
            }
        }
        catch (OperationInterruptedException ex)
        {
            //log.Error(ex);
            //DisposeAllConnectionObjects();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```